# SQLite filling null values

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have some tables with NULL values which I wish to fill with the last valid value. I can select a new table with the corrected Column, but I'm not sure how to update the values on the database, could someone help me with the update statement?

```
select b.timeStamp, 
       b.var_5, 
     (select a.var_5  from wme_test as a where a.timeStamp<=b.timeStamp  and a.var_5 <> 'NULL' order by timestamp desc limit 1 )  as correctedVar5 
from wme_test as b
```

the output for this query is this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated update to do this.

```
update wme_test 
set var5 = (select var5 
            from wme_test 
            where tm >= wme_test.tm and var5 is not null 
            order by tm limit 1)
where var5 is null
```

[**`Sample Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ff8ed/1)

Note that the earliest timestamp in the table can't be updated with this. It would still be `null`, if it was `null` previously.

Comment: ... or you can "write a very short program, or stored-procedure," which is probably what *I, personally* would choose to do, if only because I can then **more-readily *see*** "what the computer's really gonna do, and why." ### *(No, I'm not disputing your Answer: in fact, I up-voted it.)*

Comment: for this specific application I believe running this query just works best, thank you very much, I did try something like that at first but wasn't sure on  how to reefer to the outer table instead of the inner (meaning the one of the subquery) one when both are the same table. at the end  I just had to add the descending order and set the variable names, the query ended up like this: update wme_test 
set var_13 = (select var_13 
        from wme_test as b
        where timeStamp <= wme_test.timeStamp and var_13 is not null 
        order by timeStamp desc limit 1)
where var_13 is null